# Definition of OLOs Bond (Linear Bonds)

Tags: fixed-income

I'm hearing more and more about OLOs Bonds or Linear bonds, Can someone please explain the difference between this and classic bond ?

Answer (score 2):

OLO, or Obligations Linéaires Ordinaires (Linear Ordinary Bonds), basically are Belgian government bonds. They are not really much different than other government bonds paying coupons except that the same bond is issued at different points in time, hence the linearity, to increase liquidity and attractiveness of the bonds. You can check out the [Belgian Debt Agency’s page on OLO](https://www.debtagency.be/en/productoloinfo) for further details.